# checking for boolean/null to sort in Django sqlite3

Tags: django, syntax, sqlite, null, boolean

I want to serve up entries for voting one at a time, starting with the latest unvoted, moving down to the oldest unvoted. If all entries have been voted on, I want to display a random voted entry.

In the Entry model I have a voted boolean;

**models**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
  text = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
  voted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.text
  def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
  was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
  was_published_recently.boolean = True
  was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
```

In entries:views I define the entries that get displayed in tables and for voting:

**views**

```
def index(request):
 context = {
  'latest_entry_list': Entry.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10],
  'high_entry_list': Entry.objects.order_by('-score')[:10],
  'low_entry_list': Entry.objects.order_by('score')[:10],
  'voting_entry_list': Entry.objects.filter(voted = False).order_by('-pub_date')[:1],
 }
 return render(request, 'entries/index.html', context);
```

**'voting_entry_list': Entry.objects.filter(voted = False).order_by('-pub_date')[:1],**

I call it a voting list, but it consists of just the sorted entry to show for voting.

This takes care of displaying the latest unvoted entries, and I know I need to check if voted is True, and in that case display a random entry, but i can't seem to get the syntax right to do this. I think a check on voted=False returns a null could let me do an else function to pick a random entry, but I can't seem to get it going in my code.

Could someone make a suggestion?

Comment: You could get both. And then in the `index.html` use `if not voting_entry_list: ...` so it will show all the un-voted(if true show voting_entry_list, because voting_entry_list is **not** empty). `else` if all entered have been voted, display a random voted entry. I'm not an expert, but it sounds logical to me.

Comment: That should work, and makes sense. I guess I was hoping for one line of elegant code to do it. I'll keep trying, but keep that one for when I get fed up :) ....thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom model manager for `Entry` model.

`class EntryManager(models.Manager):
    def unvoted_or_random(self):
        unvoted_entries = self.filter(voted = False).order_by('-pub_date')
        if unvoted_entries:
            return unvoted_entries[:1]
        else:
            return self.all()[:1]` #or any thing else you want

and then in your `Entry` model you can do something like.

`class Entry(models.Model):
     ... 
     objects = EntryManager()`

and then you can get your required entries in the views by

`Entry.objects.unvoted_or_random()`

and pass it into the context..

I hope it would help..

Comment: Interesting, have to get my head around that. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I works as long as there are unvoted, but as soon as there are all voted, the voting entry is stuck on the last voted and stays there.

Comment: You can easily change that behavior.. In the `unvoted_or_random` function the else part of the if statements deals with that case. What I did is, just select the first element. You can select any random number by `[random_number:random_number +1]`, as a long as `number + 1` is in the range of the size of the list, which can also be calculated. and you can use pick the random number by some of your own techniques or can use some method from the standerd library..

Comment: I'll continue to look into that, but I will also look at something like this; 

    'voting_entry_list': Entry.objects.extra(select={"voting":"COALESCE(-pub_date, voted)"}, order_by=["-voting"])

Comment: Did it by adding two lines...voted_entries = self.filter(voted = True).order_by('?') AND else: return voted_entries[:1] -----This is not perfect for large databases I think, but works for now:) Thanks Darwesh.

Comment: This link was useful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/QJk3HDYAkro